# Angular 5, is the translation pipe impure?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript, ngx-translate

I am using **ngx-translate**.

Is the translation pipe pure or impure?
And is it better to use the directive syntax `translate="X"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

translation pipe is **impure**. As it is  required to update the value when the promise is resolved.
And far as usage is concerned you can either use pipe or directive and I think both have same performance.